# How to Enable and implement google ecommerce tracking in laravel project

Tags: laravel-5, google-analytics, e-commerce

I created new page for testing of ecommerce tracking. It shows page view but not show any transaction and Item added on dashboard.

Here is my script which is added in `<body>` tag of page.

attribute to load the script asynchronously. -->

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->   
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'trackingcode', 'auto');
ga('require', 'ecommerce');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '1234',
  'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',
  'revenue': '11.99',
  'shipping': '5',
  'tax': '1.29',
});
ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>

<script>
ga('require', 'ecommerce')
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': '1234',
    'name': 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',
    'sku': 'DD23444',
    'category': 'Party Toys',
    'price': '11.99',
    'quantity': '1',
});
ga('ecommerce:send');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

And in `<head>` tag I added below code:

```
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-116940006-1');
</script>
```

Comment: `gtag` and `ga` are 2 separate libraries. choose one (I personally would choose `ga`, `gtag` being fairly new and from I what I here and there, no so greatly documented/supported.

Comment: I am also using `ga` but it not workin. so I added `gtag`

Comment: adding other libraries won't help you fix `ga`. Instead you should use a debugger and find out what exactly doesn't work: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

Comment: Ok. I am removing other libraries like gtag. Trying to debug.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Only one library required either `ga` or `gtag`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must add a `@yield` with `google-ecommerce` name in your header:

```
@yield('google-ecommerce')
```

then in your `Thank you page` (last page after the transaction) add this code :

```
@extends('front.layouts.master')


@section('google-ecommerce')
    <script>
        gtag('event', 'purchase', {
            "affiliation": "Google online store",
            "value": 23.07,
            "currency": "USD",
            "tax": 1.24,
            "transaction_id": '{{ $pay->invoice_num }}',
            "shipping"      : '{{ $pay->price }}',
            "items"         : [
                {
                    "id"      : '{{ $pay->id }}',
                    "name"    : '{{ $pay->title }}',
                    "category": '{{ $pay->category }}',
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "price"   : '{{ $pay->price }}'
                }
            ]
        });
    </script>
@endsection



@section('content')
    //-------
    //-------
@endsection
```

see this link :

[Enhanced ecommerce with gtag.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce)